# I need to write a oracle sql query as from date < to date and i should exit if it's a future date in Perl

Tags: sql, oracle, perl

I have a perl script to fetch the data from Db in a particular period for that i need to write a script to validate the, user asking period dates are valid or not

Start and end dates are tacking from user like 01-JUL-16 12-JUL-16, below is my
code that i wrote, unfortunately it is not working, not sure why

```
my $dt=`date +%d-%m-%Y`;
chop $dt;
my @res1 = `sqlplus -S $logon <<EOF
set echo off
set heading off
select case when '$start_dt' > '$end_dt' then 1 else 0 ||','|| when `$end_dt' > '$dt' then 2 else 3 end from dual;
quit;
EOF`;

foreach( @res1 )
{
 chop;
next if /^$/;
next if !/HCL/;
my @fields = undef;
@fields = split(/\s+/,$_);
if ( $fields[0] eq "1")
  {
   die"start dat is greater than end date\n";
  }
  else
  {
   print"st dt less than end_dt";
  }
  if( $fields[1] eq "2")
      {
        print"you gave future date, u wnat proced [Y/N] \n"
        $a=<>;
        if($a eq "Y" || $a eq "y")
         {
          print"u gave yes\n";
         }
          else
           {
             die "exiting due to futur date\n"
            }
      }
}
```

#### Update

Perl reformatted to make it readable

```
my $dt = `date +%d-%m-%Y`;
chop $dt;

my @res1 = `sqlplus -S $logon <<EOF
set echo off
set heading off
select case when '$start_dt' > '$end_dt' then 1 else 0 ||','|| when `$end_dt' > '$dt' then 2 else 3 end from dual;
quit;
EOF`;

foreach (@res1) {

    chop;

    next if /^$/;
    next if !/HCL/;

    my @fields = undef;
    @fields = split( /\s+/, $_ );

    if ( $fields[0] eq "1" ) {
        die "start dat is greater than end date\n";
    }
    else {
        print "st dt less than end_dt";
    }

    if ( $fields[1] eq "2" ) {

        print "you gave future date, u wnat proced [Y/N] \n"
        $a = <>;

        if ( $a eq "Y" || $a eq "y" ) {
            print "u gave yes\n";
        }
        else {
            die "exiting due to futur date\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use backticks to get the date when you have perl builtin `localtime`. Why do this at all when you can use the Oracle built in for dates. Don't use backticks to automate sqlplus. use [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI)/with [DBD::Oracle](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle) along with bind variables and placeholders (see http://bobby-tables.com/ for example). Some variables in the above are undefined in your script provided. `if($a eq "Y" || $a eq "y")` is better written `if ( uc( $a ) eq 'Y' ){` but be aware that `$a` is a [special variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)

Comment: Avalanche, Sorry,It's a typo mistake, now i gave coorectly like    select case when '$start_dt' > '$end_dt' then 1 else 0 ||','|| when '$end_dt' > '$dt' then 2 else 3 end from dual;  and for the variable a i gave my $a =<>; even though this code is not executing at all

Comment: Yes Dr.Avalanche oracle has built in dates, but my situation is user will give the dates like from and to dates ( 01-JUL-16 15-JUL-16 ), in this case i need to validate the dates, Basically i'm C programmer for an urgent issue i need to write this code, though i'm not Perl programmer. Need some help Bro

Comment: Really stupid way of programming. Why do you use `\`sqlplus...\`` instead of Perl DBD::Oracle module? Why do you use Oracle at all? You select from `dual` to compare two dates! Use basic perl functions for that. Maybe the [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.34/lib/DateTime.pm) module helps you.

Comment: When you say *"unfortunately it is not working"* you mean it doesn't even compile, and your indenting is dreadful. So you haven't even bothered creating something that you can start to debug before you post your attempt online for others to fix. What do you normally do when you need something that you don't have the skills for, and it's not software? You don't see authors posting a half-finished story on line and asking for help to get it readable.

Comment: @Wernfrid  `sqlplus...` it's kind of base code, already we have scripts they used the same fashion so that i used, i'm new to SQL and Perl

Comment: It is getting compiled and my sql query also returns the correct result, Now the problem is i'm not able to fetch and validate correctly, I have removed  next if !/HCL/; in side for loop   Now the loop is getting called 1 time before it's gtting called 3 times  not sure why? and also it is not called the proper if condition. I gave two arguments 01-Jul-16 as start date and 01-Jun-16 as end date, but it is always executing the negative case. I think something wrong in if condition

Comment: @Siva: The code that you have posted here will not compile. If your original version is compiling then please copy and paste that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your question you want to compare `$start_dt`, `$end_dt`, and `$dt`.

It would make things easier if you'd told us *exactly* what the actual values of these variables are (and ideally how they are obtained). For the future, please state their *exact* format. "*Like* 01-JUL-16" is not something a Perl program can interpret without further details. The expression "1-July-2016" is also *like* "01-JUL-16" -- somehow, at least.

Having said that, I suggest the following code. It firstly converts the user input into values that are easier to compare and then does so with simple string comparison operators.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

# data from user input
my $start_dt = '01-JUL-16';
my $end_dt   = '12-JUL-16';

# convert user input to upper case ("uc") in case the input is mixed
# and/or lower case. for lower case use "lc" and adjust the line
# with "%MONTH_NUMBERS = ..." accordingly.
$start_dt = uc($start_dt);
$end_dt   = uc($end_dt);

# create a hash with "JAN=>1, FEB=>2, MAR=>3, ..." in your current locale
my %MONTH_NUMBERS = map { uc( POSIX::strftime( "%b", 0, 0, 0, 1, $_ - 1, 95 ) ) => $_ } ( 1 .. 12 );

# returns "now" in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD' (e.g. for today '2016-07-16')
my $dt = POSIX::strftime( '%Y-%m-%d', localtime() );

# convert $start_dt and $end_dt into 'YYYY-MM-DD'.
# This assumes your input years are in the range 00-99 and actually mean 2000-2099.
# If that's wrong, then you need to adjust the "2000+$3" part.
$start_dt =~ s/(\d\d)-(\D\D\D)-(\d\d)/ sprintf('%d-%02d-%02d', 2000+$3, $MONTH_NUMBERS{$2}, $1) /e;
$end_dt =~ s/(\d\d)-(\D\D\D)-(\d\d)/ sprintf('%d-%02d-%02d', 2000+$3, $MONTH_NUMBERS{$2}, $1) /e;

# now the values are:
#   dt       : 2016-07-16
#   start_dt : 2016-07-01
#   end_dt   : 2016-07-12

# you can compare them now with simple string operations, i.e. 'le', 'eq', 'gt' and so forth:
if ($end_dt gt $dt) {
    print "end date is in the future\n";
} elsif ($start_dt le $end_dt) {
    print "start date is less than or equal to end date\n";
} else {
    print "start date is greater than end date\n";
}
```

Comment: ThanQ so much Perl King, this is working except when month in small letters, So now i need to take a user input whether the future date is fine for him or not If he give Yes i need to proceed if no i need to exit. searching for that code/syntax in online. Because today only i started perl programming for an urgent issue

Comment: @siva You're welcome. I updated the answer with calls to `uc` (upper case). It might be written simpler but this way it might be easier for you to follow/understand the code.

Comment: Bro, Sorry to say it's difficult to understand/learn perl in a day, so that i asked help. for the user input i'm thinking the code something like print"u gave future date u want proceed [Y/N]";  $user_input = <>; if ( $user_input eq "Y" || $user_input eq "y"){ print"proceed"; } else{die "exiting due to future date";}

Comment: @Siva Hmm... was your last comment a question? There's (almost) nothing wrong with your attempt but `$user_input = <>;` will contain the trailing newline `\n`, so drop that with `chomp($user_input);` before comparing.

Comment: Bro, it's throwing some error   [vlltcmpsclrdap01]/home/imasdev> 2TaxExt.pl 11-JUN-16 16-JUL-17
Start and end date are :11-JUN-16,16-JUL-17
end date is in the future, you want to proceed: [Y/N]
Can't open 11-JUN-16: No such file or directory at ./2TaxExt.pl line 77.
Can't open 16-JUL-17: No such file or directory at ./2TaxExt.pl line 77.
exiting due to future end date, pls give today's or past date
[vlltcmpsclrdap01]/home/imasdev>

Comment: King : Anything wrong in this code snippet?                                                                            if ($end_dte gt $dte) {
    print "end date is future, u want to go: [Y/N]\n";
    my $user_input_future = <>;
    chomp($user_input_future);
    if($user_input_future eq "Y" || $user_input_future eq "y")
    {
        print"going with future date\n";
    } else {
        die"exiting due to future date\n";
    }

} elsif ($start_dte le $end_dte) {
    print "start date is ls than or eq to end date\n";
} else {
    die "start date is gt than end date\n";
}

Comment: @Siva Look, I tried to answer your original question. To my understanding it boiled down to _"How do I compare three dates?"_. If you have further questions, please post another question, like _"How do I open a file for reading although it does not exist?"_ (you see??)

Comment: I cannot tell whether your snippet is wrong or not. It compiles (with warnings, but it compiles). You said you're a C programmer so you must be familiar with `if … then … else …` statements. They are not different in Perl. Just apply the same logic as you would in C.

Comment: Same like C only i wrote in perl also :), while debugging it seems input is not able to take the input from user/console and it is throwing error. Or may be the if condition is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

It is really difficult to guess what you try to achieve with this program. This little Perl script would do the same as your code but without any interaction with Oracle:

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);
$dt = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', localtime);

if ( $start_dt > $end_dt ) {
    die "start dat is greater than end date\n";
} else {
    print "st dt less than end_dt";
}

if ( $end_dt > $dt ) {
    print "you gave future date, u wnat proced [Y/N] \n";
    $a = <>;
    if ( $a eq "Y" || $a eq "y" ) {
        print "u gave yes\n";
    } else {
        die "exiting due to futur date\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I debugged and achieved some progress, I have a script wich will do tax caluculation, now the requirement is i need to validate the dates that user gives. Coming to the problem that i'm facing now is         my sql query showing the wrong result                                   select case when '01-JUN-16' > '01-Sep-16' then '1' else '0' end, case when '01-JUN-16' > '01-AUG-16' then '2' else '3' end from DUAL;  Out put: 0,2

Comment: I tried ur code snippet but facing some issue, It's always calling "st dt less than end_dt"  my input was 01-SEP-16 01-JUN-16

Comment: I found the issue when we give start date like 21-JUN-16 and end date like 15-JUL-16 it is checking the first number ex:  21>15 even for month also it is treating like that only Ex: Mar>JUL                 How to resolve this any idea @Wernfried